# http fetch gives different status than network?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

I must be doing something wrong, but I am trying to ping a service until I get a 200 response. When I look in the network tab in my browser (chrome), I get a 304:

[image]

However, when I print out the following code:

```
const s1 = await fetch(`./${cluster}/api`)
const s2 = await fetch(`./${cluster}/dashboard`)
console.log(s1.status, s2.status)
```

I get:

[image]

It's hard to read sorry, but it says 200 200.

Why do I get a 200 when I check the status, but a 304 in the network tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from [here](https://javascript.info/fetch-api#:%7E:text=Normally%2C%20fetch%20transparently%20follows%20HTTP,option%20allows%20to%20change%20that%3A&text=%22error%22%20%E2%80%93%20error%20in%20case,to%20process%20HTTP%2Dredirects%20manually.) (scroll down to "redirect):

> Normally, fetch transparently follows HTTP-redirects, like 301, 302 etc.

`fetch` follows HTTP redirects, so you are getting a 304, fetch will then load the page from cache, since a `304 Not Modified` means that the cached page is still valid.

Also work reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#special_redirections

Comment: Just a clarification, for a `304 Not Modified`, the browser will load from cache. I don't think there's any _"new URL"_ involved

Comment: @Phil yes you're right, I'll edit the question with the clarification, thank you

Comment: I can ask this as a different question if needed, but is there a way to get the 304 back? I tried setting to manual and error as shown in the link to no avail. Still 200.

Comment: @AdamJohnston you can probably set `redirect` to `manual`, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

Comment: Still 200, oh well. I can figure out another way to do this. Thanks again.